# What exactly a Task is, in perf sched latency?

Tags: perf

`perf sched latency` output on `perf.data` from `perf sched record` are as follows,

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Task                  |   Runtime ms  | Switches | Average delay ms | Maximum delay ms | Maximum delay at       |

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :17657:17657          |      4.809 ms |        3 | avg:    0.093 ms | max:    0.254 ms | max at:  93915.069941 s
  :24943:24943          |      0.000 ms |        1 | avg:    0.079 ms | max:    0.079 ms | max at:  93913.299158 s
  :30004:30004          |      0.000 ms |        6 | avg:    0.073 ms | max:    0.258 ms | max at:  93914.422252 s
  :29444:29444          |      0.445 ms |        9 | avg:    0.060 ms | max:    0.397 ms | max at:  93914.421628 s
  :19326:19326          |      0.143 ms |        4 | avg:    0.047 ms | max:    0.161 ms | max at:  93914.142892 s
```

Here, what exactly a Task is? Those ids specifies what? Aren't they process/thread id?  Is it possible to get the corresponding name from these ID?

Comment: How did you run `perf sched record` ? Can you also write the command you used to run both `perf sched record` and `perf sched latency` ?

Comment: @Arnabjyoti Kalita, `perf sched record sleep <seconds>` and `perf sched latency` are the commands :)

Comment: What is the linux kernel version of the system where you are running these commands on?

Comment: Its Linux 5.2.2

Comment: Both of them are thread IDs. Ideally, the `perf sched latency` command should print the command name. It is likely that the command names were not resolved (from the pid/tid) during collection from COMM records.

Comment: Please run `perf report -i perf.data -D` and see if there are `PERF_RECORD_COMM` events and see if those tids have been resolved.